# Vuetify v-tabs how to set current active tab in typescript?

Tags: typescript, tabs, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify 2.6.13, how do I set the current active tab in the typescript?  The following code doesn't seem to work, when changeTab function gets called, the activeTab.click() doesn't change the current active tab to tab 3.

Basically looking for any way to programmatically change tabs in my typescript file, any help would be appreciated.

tabs.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-tabs height="25" hide-slider=true>
        
            <v-tab href="#tab1" ref="tab1">
                <b>TAB 1</b>
            </v-tab>
            <v-tab-item value="tab1"> content 1</v-tab-item>
            
            <v-tab href="#tab2" ref="tab2">
                <b>TAB 2</b>
            </v-tab>
            <v-tab-item value="tab2"> content 2</v-tab-item>
            
            <v-tab href="#tab3" ref="tab3">
                <b>TAB 3</b>
            </v-tab>
            <v-tab-item value="tab3"> content 3</v-tab-item>
            
        </v-tabs> 
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./tabs.ts" lang="ts">
</script>
```

tabs.ts:

```
changeTab() {
   const activeTab = $(this.$refs.tab3);
   activeTab.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to the typescript because you don't even need to use `ref` to make tabs active. You can simply use `v-model` to manage the active tab. `v-model` should be bonded with the tab's value.

Here is the demo-

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      tab: "tab2",
      tabs: [
        {
          title: "TAB 1",
          value: "tab1",
          content: "content 1"
        },
        {
          title: "TAB 2",
          value: "tab2",
          content: "content 2"
        },
        {
          title: "TAB 3",
          value: "tab3",
          content: "content 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeTab(index) {
      this.tab = 'tab' + index;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</script>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn @click="changeTab(3)" color="primary">Change Tab</v-btn>
    <div>
      <v-tabs height="25" :hide-slider=true v-model="tab">
        <template v-for="(tab, index) in tabs">
          <v-tab :href="`#${tab.value}`" :ref="tab.value">
            <b>{{ tab.title }}</b>
          </v-tab>
          <v-tab-item :value="tab.value">{{ tab.content }}</v-tab-item>
        </template>
      </v-tabs>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming this v-model bonding works, I haven't tested it yet.  How do you then in typescript programmatically switch the active tab to say tab 3 if currently user is on tab 2?

Comment: Sorry, I am not much experienced with TS syntax but as you update the variables in TS, you need to do the same by updating the v-model variable with the value of the desired tab. something like, `this.tab = 'tab3'`.

Comment: that does not seem to work.  the main question is how to switch tabs programmatically in the typescript that's tied to the .vue page.

Comment: I guess it would work. You just need to update the v-model variable programmatically with the value of the desired tab. If you can create a sandbox of the above code (convert in TS), maybe I can help you forward it. I updated the answer as well.